# How generate a char arrray of a specific charset?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, char

I would like to generate a `IEnumerable<char>` with the whole `ISO 8859-1` charset. According to this definition: [to this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I tried:

```
        testCollection = Enumerable.Range(0x20, 0xFF)
                  .Select(i => Convert.ToChar(i))
                  .Where(c => (c <= 0x7E && c >= 0xA1));
```

The problem is that testCollection is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.Range(0x20, 0xFF)`???? I thought it should end at 0xff, not 0x120. (Also do you care to perform correct conversion using corresponding `Encoding` or just byte-to-char is enough for your purposes?)

Comment: Byte to char is enough

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I understood. I misread range parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c <= 0x7E && c >= 0xA1` will never be true.

Try `c <= 0xA1 && c >= 0x7E`

Actually, I would write it as:

`0x7E <= c && c <= 0xA1`

because that puts the value being tested between the two range values, which I think makes it easier to see that it's correct.

Your code is somewhat odd though; it uses an initial range of 20h to ffh, but then only uses the subsection from 7eh to a1h. Why not just use that as the initial range and lose the `Where()`?

Also you could just do it like this:

```
char start = '\x7e';
char end   = '\xa1';
var testCollection = new char[end-start+1];

for (char curr = start; curr <= end; ++curr)
    testCollection[curr - start] = curr;
```

Comment: Actually I think OP tried to cut-out Controls C1 range (0x80-0x9f) - couple Take/Skip or `Where(c => !(0x80 <= c && c <= 0x9f))` may produce better looking code (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29 for ranges in Unicode)